# How to organize navigation structure in React Native?

Tags: react-native, navigation

I'm using react-navigation library. Currently the navigation is organized in this way:

App.js:

```
const Layout = createRootNavigator(signedIn);
return (
  <AppFontLoader>
    <Layout />
  </AppFontLoader>
);
```

AppNavigator:

```
export const createRootNavigator = (signedIn = false) => {
  return createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      SignedIn: {
        screen: SignedIn
      },
      SignedOut: {
        screen: SignedOut
      }
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: signedIn ? "SignedIn" : "SignedOut"
    }
  );
};
```

AppNavigator:

```
export const SignedIn = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    MeetingsScreen: {
...
}
```

MeetingsScreen:

```
const MeetingNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  MeetingsListScreen: {
    screen: MeetingsListScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
    }
  },
  AddMeetingForm: {
    screen: AddMeetingFormScreen
  },
  MeetingScreen: {
    screen: MeetingScreen
  }
}, {initialRouteName: "MeetingsListScreen"});
```

The error is shown with the current structure:

```
You should only render one navigator explicitly in your app, and other navigators should by rendered by including them in that navigator.
```

Apparently, I shouldn't nest one navigator into another, but I'm struggling to come up with the right navigation structure.

How to organize the navigation so that I can have more layers of navigation to move between screens?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same issue, so what I ended up doing was just making one navigation. Rootstack. All routes are there. My app.js has only root stack and navigations.